# Get a reference to a Tab from outside FXML Controller

Tags: javafx

I'm playing around with JavaFX for the first time on a personal project.

I want to be able to update the content in a Tab (adding a PieChart), but from outside the FXML controller, can anyone tell me if that's possible? How would I get a reference to the relevant tab, and is there a way to specify the location of the item I am adding?

**UPDATE**: Added some example code.

Hope this gives a clear idea of what I'm trying to do:

The interface:

```
interface ChartStrategy {

    public void DisplayChart(Info info)
}
```

Two implementations:

```
public class BarChartStrategy extends ChartStrategy {

    public void DisplayChart(Info info)
    {
        // Create bar charts on specific tabs in the UI
    }
}


public class PieChartStrategy extends ChartStrategy {

    public void DisplayChart(Info info)
    {
        // Create pie charts on specific tabs in the UI
    }
}
```

The context:

```
public class ChartContext {
  private ChartStrategy strategy;

  public void setChartStrategy(ChartStrategy strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
  }

  public void drawGraphs(Info info) {
    strategy.DisplayChart(info);
  }
}
```

In my Controller, I'm reading in a file the user selects from which the data to generate the charts is parsed, .e.g.

```
 @FXML
 private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

     // Load the file and parse the data
     ...

     ChartContext charts = new ChartContext();
     charts.setChartStrategy(new PieChartStrategy());
 }
```

So my original thought was that I could draw the charts from the DisplayChart function in the implementations, but it seems that's not a good idea - can anyone give me some advice here on the best way to get this to work?

Comment: Can I ask why? This is precisely the kind of thing the controller is supposed to do. You could just define a method in the controller that returns the particular tab, and call it from where you need, but I would not recommend exposing UI components outside the controller like that.

Comment: I was trying to use the Strategy Pattern to handle displaying different chart types in the UI, by creating the charts in the UI directly from the strategy implementation. Bad idea? Taking a class on design patterns and trying to get my head around this one.

Comment: Not a bad idea, no, but you don't need to expose the UI components from the controller to do that. Define the strategy at the controller level: i.e. your controller has a reference to a field whose type is the strategy (interface). Create the controller in code (instead of in FXML), specifying a strategy implementation which is passed to the controller's constructor. Then your controller can invoke the strategy and place the chart in the appropriate tab.

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question to include a simple example of what you want to do. That way it will be easier for someone to help by filling in the missing pieces.

Comment: @James_D, I added an example above. Hope this helps clarify what I'm trying to do!

Comment: Certainly does. See if the posted answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor this a bit.

First, letting the strategy display the chart is a bit inflexible. You are giving the strategy two responsibilities: first to decide how to represent the data visually (choose a chart) and second to actually display it somewhere. That violates the single responsibility principle.

So I would do

```
interface ChartStrategy {

    public Chart generateChart(Info info)
}
```

and similarly for the implementations, of course. Then the responsibility of the strategy is simply to provide a chart: the context can decide what to do with it.

(You can also consider whether returning a `Chart` here is too rigid: maybe you just want it to return a `Parent`, or `Node`. Then your "chart" could be, e.g., a `TableView`, for example.)

In the theoretical descriptions of the strategy pattern, at least in my interpretation, the "context" just represents "something that is using the strategy". So your context is likely a view or controller (depending on your choice of MVC variant...). As a trivial example you might have something like

```
public class ChartTab {

    private ChartStrategy chartGenerator ;

    public void setChartGenerator(ChartStrategy chartGenerator) {
      this.chartGenerator = chartGenerator ;
    }

    public Tab createChartTab(Info info) {
        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setContent(chartGenerator.generateChart(info));
        return tab ;
    }
}
```

and then in your controller

```
@FXML
private TabPane tabPane ;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    // Load the file and parse the data
    ...

    ChartTab chartTab = new ChartTab();
    chartTab.setChartGenerator(new PieChartStrategy());
    tabPane.getTabs().add(chartTab.getTab(info));    
}
```

It's also possible just to consider the controller the context (if for a fixed controller you are just creating one kind of chart, which depends on how you split up the FXML files and their corresponding controllers):

```
public class MyController {

    private ChartStrategy chartGenerator ;

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane ;

    public MyController(ChartStrategy chartGenerator) {
        this.chartGenerator = chartGenerator ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        // Load the file and parse the data
        ...

        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setContent(chartGenerator.generateChart(info));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);    
    }

}
```

Note this controller doesn't have a no-arg constructor, so you cannot use the `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file (i.e. remove that attribute from the FXML file). Instead, you'd do

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader("/path/to/DataDisplay.fxml");
MyController controller = new MyController(new PieChartStrategy());
loader.setController(controller);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Now you have an FXML and controller with the functionality to generate charts and display them in a tab pane (or whatever), but the details of what kind of chart is generated are factored out into a pluggable strategy. You still have the proper MVC (or MVP, etc etc) encapsulation in which the details of the UI are kept private to the view-controller (here it's really a presenter, but who's counting...) pair. In other words the strategy knows nothing about the rest of the view, which is as it should be.

Comment: Thanks @James_D, this gives me lots of food for thought.